# Is Redis a single point of failure in this scenario (Redis, Node.JS, Socket.IO) ?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, scalability

I use Redis because it allows me to scale my applications horizontally (multiple servers). By using it's pub sub features all my servers can communicate with each other without needing to share memory.

So far, cool! We can add more nodejs servers, BUT all this servers subscribe to one single Redis server. So we have the situation in which we have many NodeJs servers communication to just one Redis server, we can serve more clients but still we have one Redis.

From my tests the Redis server uses less resources so can handle more, but still in this design I think is a SPF. What do you think?

What are the best ways to design a scalable system? I know about master/slave Redis but still I am not convinced if it is the best solution.

Comment: This question might be better suited to [Software Engineering SE](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), given that it's focused on infrastructure setup rather than a specific programming issue.

Comment: @JoeClay when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: What aren't you convinced about? Redis replication with sentinel seems the best solution for what you've described.

Comment: @gnat: Yeah, good point!

Comment: This is also why many are starting to use Redis Enterprise Pack as is designed to get around this and even some of the short comings of cluster and sentinel. Your application does not have to change at all, it does its HA and availability in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Redis is a single point of failure in what you describe. Not only in a sense that when it is down then your app is down, but also in the sense that if one of your processes remove or corrupt the data then it is lost forever.

What you can do is use multiple Redis servers and have a good backup strategy.

See this tutorial for clustering:

- https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

See these tutorials for backups:

- http://zdk.blinkenshell.org/redis-backup-and-restore/
- https://redis.io/topics/persistence
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-and-restore-your-redis-data-on-ubuntu-14-04